# Set labels of radio button group dynamically based on values selected in drop down lists

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html form with 4 form elements - 3 drop down lists and one group of radio buttons.

I want the label of the radio buttons to be set dynamically based on the values selected in the drop down lists.

Ex- The values selected in the drop down lists are q-tip, hold and h1 rspectively.
So, the labels in the radio button group (Direction) should be:

1. First radio button - q-tip hold h1.
2. Second radio button - h1 hold q-tip

[image]

This is the jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/coderr/yznf1qk3/22/

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <h5>Object</h5>
  <select name="object" id="object">
    <option value="q-tip">q-tip</option>
    <option value="o2">o2</option>
  </select>
</div>



<div style="float:left;">
  <h5>Action</h5>
  <select name="action" id="action">
    <option value="hold">hold</option>
    <option value="a2">a2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
  <h5>Person</h5>
  <select name="humann" id="human">
    <option value="h1">h1</option>
    <option value="h2">h2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Direction</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="direction" value="towards">q-tip hold h1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="direction" value="away">h1 hold q-tip<br>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with the JS you have tried. Your examples are not clear at all

Comment: Hi @mplungjan . Thank You for your reply. That is the entire code I have tried. I am not sure how to convert it to javascript because all the examples I saw involve changing something when clicking a radio button. But, I want the label of the radio buttons to change when the values selected in the drop down lists change. The link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coderr/yznf1qk3/22/

Comment: The JSFiddle is identical to the snippet here. Please explain step by step what you click and what you expect to happen and `$("#object option:selected").text();` does nothing inside HTML and the q-tip humann favorite pet is not making any sense so please use better content

Comment: I think the OP wants the "javascript" to be executed and result displayed at the location.

Comment: @mplungjan Oh ok. I got your question. So, the values selected in the drop down lists are q-tip, hold and h1 respectively. So, I want the radio buttons to have the following labels. Radio button 1 - q-tip hold h1. Radio button 2 - h1 hold q-tip.

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated the jsfiddle link with the expected radio button labels

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/coderr/yznf1qk3/24/ Sorry, I just realized the link in the question has the old version of the code. This link has the changes I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: WHY not update the SNIPPET here in the question???? Just click [edit], scroll down and click `edit above snippet` No need to leave Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some HTML to make it easier to access the text

```js
$("#selects").on("change",function() { // any change of selects
  const dirs = $(this).find("select").map(function() { return this.value }).get(); // get the values in an array
  const $rads = $("[name=direction]"); // the radios
  $rads.eq(0).next().text(dirs.join(" ")); // update the span after the radio - I wrapped in label too
  dirs.reverse(); // reverse the array
  $rads.eq(1).next().text(dirs.join(" ")); // add to the second radio span
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selects">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <h5>Object</h5>
    <select name="object" id="object">
      <option value="q-tip">q-tip</option>
      <option value="o2">o2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <h5>Action</h5>
    <select name="action" id="action">
      <option value="hold">hold</option>
      <option value="a2">a2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left;">
    <h5>Person</h5>
    <select name="humann" id="human">
      <option value="h1">h1</option>
      <option value="h2">h2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Direction</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="direction" value="towards"><span>q-tip hold h1</span></label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="direction" value="away"><span>h1 hold q-tip</span></label><br>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank You so much!